# Invert logo for dark background but keep color hue? (in pure CSS)

Tags: css

Whats the best way to make a logo image that was made for a light background look good on a dark background in CSS? I know there's `filter: invert(1)`, but that inverts all the colors, and the logo looks entirely different.

with `filter: invert(1)`: [image]

Answer (score 6):

You can use:

```css
img.dark {
  filter: invert(1) hue-rotate(180deg);
}
```

The `hue-rotate` turns all of your colors back to the hue before the `invert`, so for example the StackOverflow icon becomes:

original: [image]

`invert(1)`: [image]

`invert(1) hue-rotate(180deg)`: [image]

**However**, if your logo is especially complex this will likely not work for you, since all of your lighter colors will turn dark, e.g.:

original: [image]

`invert(1)`: [image]

`invert(1) hue-rotate(180deg)`: [image]

Comment: *your logo is especially complex this will likely not work for you* so this isn't really a robust solution? It would be good to show more examples with other logos so we can see when it's good and when not

Comment: @TemaniAfif added